# tumblr background image stretched vertically in mobile

Tags: html, css, image, background, tumblr

I have a Tumblr page styled using [this theme](http://olleotathemes.tumblr.com/theme/signature), and I want a full page background image. No matter what I try, it looks great on desktop, but on mobile (Safari in iOS 10.3.1) the image becomes stretched out vertically as I add more content to the page. The result looks highly pixelated and looks terrible.

I first tried uploading the image directly using Tumblr's theme customization options, but now I'm working with this custom CSS:

```
html, body {
min-height: 100%;
}
body {
background-image: url(http://myurl.com/myimage.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
background-size: cover;
}
@media (min-width: 1120px), (min-height: 630px) {
body { background-size: auto; }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: try setting background-size: 100% 100%

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the background size from auto to cover?